# Understanding C++ map why heap memory isn't released with clear()?

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap

Suppose I have a forever loop to create hashmap:

```
void createMap() {
    map<int, int> mymap;
    for (int i = 0; i < INT_MAX; i++) {
        mymap[i] = i;
    }
    mymap.clear();       // <-- this line doesn't seem to make a difference in memory growth
}

int main (void) {

    while (1) {
        createMap();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I watched the code run and on MacOS, watching the Activity Monitor, the application keeps growing the memory usage with or without the `mymap.clear()` at end of the `createMap()` function.

Shouldn't memory usage be constant for the case where `mymap.clear()` is used?

What's the general recommendation for using STL data containers? Need to `.clear()` before end of function?

Comment: The .clear() will happen even if you dont call it as part of destructor. So the fact that it does not make a difference is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I asked in another forum, the folks there helped me understand the answer. It turns out, I didn't wait long enough to exit `createMap` function nor do I have enough memory to sustain this program.

It takes INT_MAX=2147483647 elements to be created, and for each `map = 24 bytes` element of `pair<int, int> = 8 bytes`.

Total minimum memory = 2.147483647^9 * 8 + 24 = `17179869200 bytes ~= 17.2 GB`.

I reduced the size of the elements and tested both with and without `.clear()` the program grew and reduce in size accordingly.

Comment: If you have a 64-bit OS, and compile your program for 64-bit,  and sufficient enough disk space for virtual memory, it will run forever with `MAX_INT` iterations.  And if you have say 32GB of RAM installed, it might actually run just fine without needing to swap.

Answer (score 0):

The container you create is bound to the scope of your function. If the function returns, its lifetime ends. And as `std::map` owns its data, the memory it allocates is freed upon destruction.

Your code hence constantly allocates and frees the same amount of memory. Memory consumption is hence constant, although the exact memory locations will probably differ. This also means that you should not manually call `clear` at the end of this function. Use `clear`  when you want to empty a container that you intend to continue using afterwards.

As a side note, `std::map` is *not* a hash map (`std::unordered_map` is one).

Comment: Noted on when to use .clear(). What I wonder is that why the memory usage keeps growing when I run the code? Shouldn't it stay constant? And cool to know about ```std::unordered_map```.

Comment: Not sure why it should be growing. Maybe some virtual memory effect at work.